# How do I authenticate my existing users through my bot?

Tags: botframework

I am creating a bot that will allow users to interact with an existing web service. I want users to be able to start a conversation with my bot and retrieve information that is personalized to them.

How do I match a bot user with their existing account? Not all channels use an email address, so I can't use that for matching.

I thought about putting a link in the chat window that says something like "You need to register with the bot framework before continuing", and provide a link back to my service that contains their Bot Framework global UserId. I can then store this Id in my existing service's database, and use it to authenticate the user.

Is there a better way to do this? Are bots supposed to be treated as standalone applications?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to identify a user you can simply ask them for identifying information.

If you need to authenticate we usually recommend sending a link that does an auth flow and then store the access token on the UserBotData so you have it for future messages.

Comment: So after sending a user through an auth flow, how do I send the token back to the specific UserBotData session? Do you know of any documentation for this?

Comment: How do you tie that user to the account? For instance web chat always generate new userid every time browser page is refreshed, which means even if I authenticated that user he can't come back later and get personalized info from the bot. Is that unique for web chat since skype for instance will have same username?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look to the [Facebook Auth sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot) to get an idea of a potential flow for the Auth scenario. For Azure AD, you need to do a similar flow.

Also, in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950160/how-to-get-azure-active-directory-b2c-working-with-bot-framework/37002612#37002612) we discussed about how to do it against Azure AD.

*Update*

There are two new samples that you might want to take a look since they are implementing the workflow being discussed.

- [GraphBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/develop/CSharp/Samples/GraphBot/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.GraphBot) from the BotBuilder repo.
- [AuthBot](https://github.com/matvelloso/AuthBot) from Mat Velloso

Comment: @Dave, did you find any solution? I am also facing same challenge.

Comment: I found [this Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/09/06/microsoft-bot-framework-bot-with-authentication-and-signin-login/) which provides three different methods for accomplishing this task, and includes links to some Github sample code.