# Enterprise bot with authentication

Tags: botframework

is it possible to secure a bot from microsofts botframework with azure ad or just active directory?

Will it be possible to just publish the bot for one company?

Kind regards,
prog1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get Azure Active Directory B2C working with Bot Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950160/how-to-get-azure-active-directory-b2c-working-with-bot-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the Facebook Auth sample bot ([here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot)).  It showcases OAuth authentication using Facebook graph API.  (I've seen a bot that uses Active Directory, but don't have a sample handy.)