# Using Azure AD B2C with Bot

Tags: .net, azure, botframework, bots, azure-ad-b2c

I've created a bot in Azure that uses a `SignInCard` to give users the option to log-in or register as customers. This is the `SignInCard` I currently have:

```
messageActivity.Attachments.Add(new SigninCard()
            {
                Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
                {
                    new CardAction()
                    {
                        Title = "Log in here",
                        DisplayText = "Log in here",
                        Value = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SiUp&client_id=XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXd&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3980%2Fapi%2Flogin&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login",
                        Text = "Sign in/Register",
                        Type = ActionTypes.Signin,                        
                    }
                }                
            }.ToAttachment());
```

The **bot correctly shows the card** and when I click it, it opens the browser with the correct providers, that work perfectly (I can sign-in and register).

On my end, I have a Web API with a `LoginController` mapped to my **Return Url** (that is localhost:3980/api/login).

To verify that the Return Url is being called, I put a breakpoint in `LoginControl.Get`:

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();     //The breakpoint here is hit!
    }
}
```

After login, the Get method is called as the breakpoint is hit, But what comes next? I don't know how to proceed.

The only think I've discovered is that the `LoginController.Get`  method is being invoked by Azure B2C AD with a URL like this:

http://localhost:3980/api/login#id_token=eyJ0eXAi...

I guess it's that URL what is being called because it shows in the address bar of my browser.

So, it's sending something called "id_token", but inside the Controller.Get method I cannot seem to have access to it.

What's the id_token? How to get it?

Comment: What if you add this redirect URI to your Azure AD B2C application and then use it with the `CardAction.Value` property: `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect`?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I put that URL and a white page opens showing the text "Bad Request"

Comment: Playing around, I set the Redirect URL to a URL from my Web API that maps to a controller called `LoginController`: The URL I set is this => http://localhost:3980/api/login In LoginController, I set a breakpoint in the the Get method (HttpGet). After I log in, the breakpoint is hit. The URL is like this: http://localhost:3980/api/login#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsifQ.eyJleHAiOjE1MzI2MDEzNTUsIm5iZiI6MTUzMjU5Nzc1NSwidm.... how do I handle it? It comes with and id_token.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I've updated the question with my latest findings. I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get Azure Active Directory B2C working with Bot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950160/how-to-get-azure-active-directory-b2c-working-with-bot-framework)

Answer (score 1):

[AuthBot](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot) and also [BotAuth](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/tree/master/CSharp) are samples which contain authentication implementation approaches.

You have to use Graph Api for to getting user principles using token received from authenticator service (More specific to Azure Active Directory). Token will receive in call back url which you have configured in AAD application.

In samples, you will get a complete implementation of user authentication.

Hope this will help you.