# Auth provider settings for MS Botframework using Azure B2C

Tags: botframework, azure-ad-b2c

How do I setup Azure B2C as an auth provider for the botbuilder framework? Under "setting" we can add a provider (e.g. generic oauth2.0), but what are the correct URLs and scopes?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get Azure Active Directory B2C working with Bot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950160/how-to-get-azure-active-directory-b2c-working-with-bot-framework)

Answer (score 1):

Bot Framework provides documentation on how to setup OAuth in the docs portion of their website. I don't know if you're looking for a v3 or v4 solution, but both go into depth. You an read about the v3 implementation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) and about v4 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).

Hope of help!

Comment: we are using https://<tenant>.b2clogin.com/cmbenterpriseauth.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sgninup/oauth2/v2.0/authorize as the URL and openid profile for scopes. We never get a token back, also from test tab in settings.

Comment: Is this v3 or v4 and Node or C#?

Comment: @Timo the 2nd that Steven Kanberg provided has v4 instructions for both C# and JS. Are you encountering an error in particular? Or have you resolved your issue?