# Any advice / sample for authenticating Bot Framework users through Azure AD B2C with dotnetcore?

Tags: .net-core, botframework, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to authenticate users of bot framework V4 with Azure AD B2C sef ices with different social media providers. I'm stuck with it. 
I have looked and try many of the DOTNETCore samples provided to use Azure ADB2C authentication. Some of them work ok (the ones with fabrikam are quite ok). 
Would any one have some experience on that or any suggestions on how to proceed ? 
One thing that is not clear to me is : can I just create some controllers from with my Bot Framework project with the proper Azure AD B2C settings  (tenant, poloicies, appid, key, etc ... ) ? or do I necessarily have to create a Web App or a WebApi to which post the authentication requests ?

Here are the samples I have already tried with no much success from github : 
- active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2-master
- active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi-master
- active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp-master

and I'm a bit lost on what should be the right approach. 
Any advice would be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use a sign-in card with an OAuth prompt or something like that? Have you had a look at the authentication samples? What SDK are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get Azure Active Directory B2C working with Bot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950160/how-to-get-azure-active-directory-b2c-working-with-bot-framework)

Answer (score 0):

you can take this one and adapt: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot

The difference is that this sample is specific for Facebook, so it will generate an oauth string that will send the user straight to facebook's page. In your scenario you will need to generate an oauth URL that will take the user to AAD B2C's auth page (basically following these guidelines:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc/.

Also you can refer this latest thread for further [reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2017/05/15/bot-authentication-in-the-bot-framework/).

Hope it helps.