# How to authenticate Microsoft chatbot with Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-bot-service

I want to authenticate my chatbot with Azure AD B2C, instead of Azure AD. I followed the Microsoft documentation.
[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp)

But instead Azure AD, I used Azure B2C to set up the connection and the rest. But when running the bot, It's redirecting me to Azure AD. I can't log in with the B2C account that I created.

Are there any options to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's possible, according to the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-scenario-commerce?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Did you tried to replace the "Azure AD identity service" paragraph https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp#azure-ad-identity-service
with B2C application registration documentation?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga#register-a-web-application

There is also an interesting b2clogin.com URL sign-in article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin

It's also such a question, which I found: [how to get Azure Active Directory B2C working with Bot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950160/how-to-get-azure-active-directory-b2c-working-with-bot-framework)

Comment: Thank you, sir.  Was able to fix it using the 3rd link you provided.